Error: `Cannot find module` when npm test using nest typescript
I’m encountering an error when attempting to execute command npm run. Despite exploring various solutions and troubleshooting steps suggested in other forums and documentation, I haven’t been able to resolve the issue. Could you please provide guidance or suggest a method to address this problem effectively?
the error i get
  FAIL  test/app.e2e-spec.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

Cannot find module 'src/category/category.module' from '../src/info/info.module.ts'

Require stack:
  D:/astagatra-web/server/src/info/info.module.ts
  D:/astagatra-web/server/src/app.module.ts
  app.e2e-spec.ts

  1 | import { Module } from "@nestjs/common";
  2 | import { DynamooseModule } from "nestjs-dynamoose";
> 3 | import { CategoryModule } from "src/category/category.module";
    | ^
  4 | import { SharedServiceModule } from "src/shared/services/service.module";
  5 | import { UserModule } from "src/user/user.module";
  6 | import { InfoPublicController } from "./controller/info.public.controller";

  at Resolver.resolveModule (../node_modules/jest-resolve/build/resolver.js:324:11)
  at Object.<anonymous> (../src/info/info.module.ts:3:1)

package.json
{
  "name": "nest-server",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "engines": {
    "npm": ">=7.0.0",
    "node": ">=14.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=prod node dist/main",
    "start:dev": "NODE_ENV=dev nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": " NODE_ENV=prod node dist/main",
    "start:prod-local": "ALLOW_ALL=true NODE_ENV=prod nest start",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json",
    "deploy": "npm run build && eb deploy"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider": "^3.53.0",
    "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.53.1",
    "@aws-sdk/client-ses": "^3.56.0",
    "@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner": "^3.53.1",
    "@kurkle/color": "^0.1.9",
    "@nestjs/common": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/config": "^1.1.7",
    "@nestjs/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/jwt": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/mapped-types": "*",
    "@nestjs/passport": "^8.2.1",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/schedule": "^1.0.2",
    "@nestjs/swagger": "^5.1.5",
    "@nestjs/throttler": "^2.0.0",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "^8.0.2",
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/cache-manager": "^3.4.3",
    "@types/cron": "^1.7.3",
    "@types/express-session": "^1.17.4",
    "@types/html-pdf": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.178",
    "@types/mime": "^2.0.3",
    "@types/multer": "^1.4.7",
    "@types/multer-s3": "^2.7.11",
    "@types/mustache": "^4.1.2",
    "@types/nodemailer": "^6.4.4",
    "@types/passport-local": "^1.0.34",
    "@types/sanitize-html": "^2.6.2",
    "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^5.2.6",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1087.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "cache-manager": "^3.6.0",
    "class-transformer": "^0.4.0",
    "class-validator": "^0.13.1",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "dynamoose": "^2.8.5",
    "express-mysql-session": "^2.1.7",
    "express-session": "^1.17.2",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "fuzzysort": "^1.2.1",
    "html-pdf": "^3.0.1",
    "jwks-rsa": "^2.0.5",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "mime": "^3.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "multer": "^1.4.3",
    "multer-s3": "^2.10.0",
    "mustache": "^4.2.0",
    "nestjs-dynamoose": "^0.3.4",
    "node-fetch": "^3.2.0",
    "nodemailer": "^6.7.2",
    "passport": "^0.5.2",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^7.2.0",
    "sanitize-html": "^2.7.0",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^4.1.6",
    "utils-decorators": "^2.0.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.9",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.11",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.0.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "jest": "^27.2.5",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.20",
    "supertest": "^6.1.3",
    "ts-jest": "^27.0.3",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.0.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.10.1",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  
  }

  
}

tsconfig.json
 "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false

info.module.ts
import { Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { DynamooseModule } from "nestjs-dynamoose";
import { CategoryModule } from "src/category/category.module";
import { SharedServiceModule } from "src/shared/services/service.module";
import { UserModule } from "src/user/user.module";
import { InfoPublicController } from "./controller/info.public.controller";
import { InfoController } from "./controller/info.tools.controller";
import { CommentSchema } from "./schema/comment.schema";
import { InfoSchema } from "./schema/info.schema";
import { LikesSchema } from "./schema/likes.schema";
import { CommentService } from "./service/comment.service";
import { InfoCache } from "./service/info.cache";
import { InfoService } from "./service/info.service";
import { LikeService } from "./service/likes.service";

@Module({
  imports: [
    SharedServiceModule,
    CategoryModule,
    UserModule,
    DynamooseModule.forFeature([
      {
        name: "info",
        schema: InfoSchema,
        options: { throughput: "ON_DEMAND" },
      },
      {
        name: "likes",
        schema: LikesSchema,
        options: { throughput: "ON_DEMAND" },
      },
      {
        name: "comment",
        schema: CommentSchema,
        options: { throughput: "ON_DEMAND" },
      },
    ]),
  ],
  controllers: [InfoController, InfoPublicController],
  providers: [InfoService, LikeService, CommentService, InfoCache],
  exports: [InfoCache],
})
export class InfoModule {}


what if you use relative imports instead of absolute ones (those with prefix src/)?

@MicaelLevi like dist/src/main?

no, I'm talking about imports. Instead of import ... from "src/category/category.module", try a relative path

try using but still  Error: Cannot find module '../src/category/category.module'

then I have no ideia what else it could be

I got the same error and I solved with this approach:

You need to configure the moduleNameMapper in Jest to match your tsconfig.json paths. Here is how:


Update your tsconfig.json :
"baseUrl": ".",
"paths": {
  "src/*": ["./src/*"]
}


Then update Jest configuration (in package.json) adding a moduleNameMapper:


`
 "jest": {
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "^src/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/$1"
  }
 }

`

Which version of Nest are you using? Nest transpiles with TSC so you get a direct copy output tree in your dist where files all call each other, and it doesn't 'compile' like you might be thinking with webpack / jest / ts-jest into a virtual thing for testing.
Either run TSC first so you have a JS version of your app, then run the e2e tests against those files.
If you have the latest version then you need to explicitly tell the testing library which modules you want to make available to App when it 'compiles' in memory (it won't write files). So in this case need to add Category Module so that it's in scope for InfoModule to 'find' when compiling. Hope that makes sense sorry.
